# C Program - Add integers from while loop together

Tags: c, console

I'm trying to create a simple C program that will continuously ask the user to enter a number until a negative is entered, then when a negative is entered it will add all of the positive numbers entered by the user. I'm having an issue because I simply don't know how to add the numbers entered together. I've made a start and have this so far:

```
  int main()
    {
       int numbersEntered, sum;
       while(numbersEntered>0) {
       printf("Enter Numbers to add together: ");
       scanf("%d", &numbersEntered);
       }
       printf("%d", sum);
    }
```

I don't know how I can calculate the sum of all integers entered.

Comment: If you are doing homework assignments, you should be trying to do them yourself, not asking others to do it. This is an extremely simple concept, and you would have found an answer after a few minutes of researching (How to add numbers in c?)

Answer (score 0):

The program can look the following way

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main( void )
{
    int numberEntered;
    long long int sum;

    sum = 0;

    printf( "Enter numbers to add together (a negative number - exit): " );

    while( scanf( "%d", &numberEntered ) == 1 && numberEntered >= 0 ) 
    {
        sum += numberEntered;
    }

    printf( "%lld\n", sum );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use the following formula to calculate the sum :
sum =sum+numbersEntered; this is the same as the following shortcut operator
sum +=numbersEntered;
so you will add the old sum to the numbersEntered and restore it into sum 
but take care :
don't forget to initialize sum with 0 .

Answer (score 0):

Your program didn't worked because, initialy, you didn't had any value in the numbersEntered variable. You have to read a number first, because the while condition must be evaluated first. This is a way to to this very easily:

```
int main()
{
    int numbersEntered, sum=0;
    printf("Enter the first number: ");
    while ( scanf("%d", &numbersEntered) > 0 && numbersEntered > 0 )
    {
        printf("Enter another number to be added to the sum: ");
        sum += numbersEntered;
    }
    printf("\nSum is: ");
    printf("%d", sum);
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

A thing to remember: scanf function returns a value bigger than zero, if the read was carried out. And you have to initialize your sum value to 0, because if you just declare it, it will be initialized with a value from memory ( all values from a program WILL be initialized with a value, even if you won't do it ).